# R - How to iterate over dataframe rows then find and change row values that (contain) pre-defined values in another list

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, iteration

I need to check all rows of a dataframe column. If any row contains (does not have to exactly match) any of the names I pre-defined in another list, I'd like to change that row value to match that list value.

Let's say I set-up a list of pre-defined stations names

```
station_names <- c("Braintree", "Houston", "Tripoli")
```

And let's say my dataframe is as follows:

```
                        column1 column2
1  36-Houston qefwef[TC] #27770       1
2   30-Braintree wef[TC] #27770       2
3 01-Tripolifwefwef [TC] #27770       3
4       any other random string       4
5                             5       5
```

I would like to iterate over column1 rows, find those pre-defined station names, and remove the rest of the text so that my datframe would look as follwos:

```
                  column1 column2
1                 Houston       1
2               Braintree       2
3                 Tripoli       3
4 any other random string       4
5                       5       5
```

I was able to do so using the following code:

```
dataframe$column1 <- ifelse(grepl("Braintree", dataframe$column1),
                             "Braintree", dataframe$column1)

dataframe$column1 <- ifelse(grepl("Houston", dataframe$column1),
                            "Houston", dataframe$column1)

dataframe$column1 <- ifelse(grepl("Tripoli", dataframe$column1),
                            "Tripoli", dataframe$column1)
```

My code explanation:

1 - grepl: I added grepl function inside ifelse so that it searches for the station name regardless if cell has other characters before or after the name

2- iflese: if dataframe$column1 contains station name, then assign station name to the row otherwise keep the same value

My original data contains thousands of rows and about 50 station names and my code looks like bad practice, I was wondering if you can help me iterate over the process faster by running one function for all stations names

Comment: Is the third element spelling correct `01-Tripolofwefwef [TC] #27770`, but your pattern is `Tripoli`

Comment: You're right I put this together in a rush, already edited it

Answer (score 0):

We can use [`str_extract`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringr/versions/1.4.0/topics/str_extract) with [`coalesce`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.8/topics/coalesce)

1. Use `str_c` to create a single string from the 'station_names' by `collapse`ing with `|` (`OR`)
2. Use the output of 1 as `pattern` in `str_extract` to extract the word from 'column1'
3. If there are no matches, it returns `NA` by default for that element.  Use `coalesce` to replace those `NA` with the corresponding non-NA element from the original column
4. Update the 'column1' with the output of 3 in `mutate`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df1 %>%
     mutate(column1 = coalesce(str_extract(column1, 
          str_c(station_names, collapse="|")), column1))
```

-output

```
df1
                   column1 column2
1                 Houston       1
2               Braintree       2
3                 Tripoli       3
4 any other random string       4
5                       5       5
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(column1 = c("36-Houston qefwef[TC] #27770", 
  "30-Braintree wef[TC] #27770", 
"01-Tripolifwefwef [TC] #27770", "any other random string", "5"
), column2 = 1:5), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5"))
```

Comment: I ran your code but for some reason it did not change the original data at all. Thanks for the receommendation, I've never used str_extract and coalesce and I might be missing something

Comment: @bluejaziac have you assigned it back `df1 <- df1 %>%`

Comment: @bluejaziac I used the data as showed in my `data` and then got the expected